# Sleep makes shut down in HP ProBook

Tags: windows-7, sleep, shutdown

My HP ProBook 4540s has some problems. If I keep it in sleep. It shuts down automatically. I re-install my OS (Windows 7 Home Premium). But the problem is still like that..

What is the solution?

Comment: Are you running with a low battery?

Comment: No.. it happens even in the plug in mood..

Comment: Does it "shutdown" immediately after sleep or some time later?

Comment: Click `Start`, type power, and select Power Options. click `Choose when to turn off the display`. Click the `Change advanced power settings` link. Expand the Sleep section for "Sleep after" and Hibernate after" options. What do you see for the "Hibernate after" setting?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in the BIOS for any odd power settings.

I'm not familiar with the BIOS for that particular machine, but there could be an automatic shutdown or power-saving setting that's causing the computer to act that way.

Here's a link to the support site for that model. Check the manuals for details on how to access the BIOS.

[HP Support (ProBook 4540s)](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/manualsResults/?sp4ts.oid=5229455&spf_p.tpst=psiContentResults&spf_p.prp_psiContentResults=wsrp-navigationalState%3Daction%253Dmanualslist%257Ccontentid%253DGeneral-Reference%257Clang%253Den&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken)

Comment: :( I haven't a good knowledge about it...